# How can I run a command on a indexed version of the file in git repository instead of the version in working directory?

Tags: git, githooks

I want to add a `pre-commit` hook to run code checks on the files ready to be commited.

I need to run `phpcs` commands for this as part of the `pre-commit` hook. And I need to run them on the "indexed" version of the files.

However, simply doing `phpcs myfile.php`, the command runs on the "working directory" version of the file.

This means that someone can make a faulty code, add it to index, then correct that code in working directory and still be able to commit the code faulty code without adding the correct code to index as the check will run on the working directory version of the file.

So, how can I run a command on a indexed version of the file in git repository instead of the version in working directory?

Comment: So you want to be able to detect... *already corrected* errors/problems?

Comment: @RomainValeri: sort of. In particular he wants to make sure, in the pre-commit hook, that the to-be-committed copy of the file is correct.) Consider what happens with `git add -p` for instance.) @kmdhrm: this is actually quite difficult. Go to https://pre-commit.com/ to find a fancy Python package that actually does this well.